# How to change header text from another page in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing "Label Configuration" in whole web application in asp.net. My requirement is to change header text on grid view. I have created LabelConfig.aspx page and I need to changes header text in another page on same application. How can I change the header text in grid view from another page?

Comment: Populate the header from a common storage (file/db-table). Store the modified header text in there; then redirect to the page.